# iotop not working even with SIP disabled

Tags: macos, sip

I am trying to run `iotop` in order to see realtime disk usage stats. I disabled System Integrity Protection for dtrace by booting into Recovery Mode and running

```
csrutil disable
csrutil enable --without dtrace
```

This seems to have worked. Now back in user mode, I see the following (emphasis mine):

```
$> csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: unknown (Custom Configuration).

Configuration:
    Apple Internal: disabled
    Kext Signing: enabled
    Filesystem Protections: enabled
    Debugging Restrictions: enabled
    DTrace Restrictions: **disabled**
    NVRAM Protections: enabled
    BaseSystem Verification: enabled
    Boot-arg Restrictions: enabled
    Kernel Integrity Protections: disabled
    Authenticated Root Requirement: enabled

This is an unsupported configuration, likely to break in the future and leave your machine in an unknown state.
```

However, running `sudo iotop` still results in a dtrace probe specifier error:

```
$> sudo iotop
dtrace: invalid probe specifier
...
...
...
: in action list: failed to resolve : Unknown variable name
```

What other steps need to be taken to let iotop work on an M1 mac?

System details:

- Monterey version 12.0.1
- Chip: Apple M1 Pro